# Pandas Dataframe GroupBy - Displaying Group Statistics

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

For the Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
codes = ["one","two","three"];
colours = ["black", "white"];
textures = ["soft", "hard"];
N= 100 # length of the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : range(1,N+1),
                    'code' : [random.choice(codes) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'colour': [random.choice(colours) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'texture': [random.choice(textures) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'size': [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1,N+1)]
                    },  columns= ['id','code','colour', 'texture', 'size'])
```

I run the line below to get the aggregated sizes grouped by `code` and `colour` pairs:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['code', 'colour']).agg({'size' : np.sum}).reset_index()
>> grouped
>>     code colour  size
>> 0    one  black   987
>> 1    one  white   972
>> 2  three  black   972
>> 3  three  white   488
>> 4    two  black  1162
>> 5    two  white  1158
>> [6 rows x 3 columns]
```

In additon to the aggreageted (np.sum) sizes, I want to get separate columns for:

**i.** average value (np.avg) per group

**ii.** the id of the row with the max size for a given group,

**iii.** how many times the group occured (e.g. code=one, colour=black, 12 times)

**Question:** What is the fastest way to do this? Would I have to use `apply()` and a proprietary function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a list of functions to be applied to the group, e.g.:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['code', 'colour'])['size'].agg([np.sum, np.average, np.size, np.argmax]).reset_index()
```

Since `argmax` is the index of the maximum row, you will need to look them up on the original dataframe:

```
grouped['max_row_id'] = df.ix[grouped['argmax']].reset_index(grouped.index).id
```

NOTE: I selected the 'size' column because all the functions apply to that column. If you wanted to do a different set of functions for different columns, you can use `agg` with a dictionary with a list of functions e.g. `agg({'size': [np.sum, np.average]})`. This results in `MultiIndex` columns, which means that when getting the IDs for the maximum size in each group you need to do:

```
grouped['max_row_id'] = df.ix[grouped['size']['argmax']].reset_index(grouped.index).id
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I noticed that the code works for just the `size` column version but does not work when I do: `grouped = df.groupby(['code', 'colour']).agg({'size':[np.sum, np.average, np.size, np.argmax]}).reset_index(); grouped['max_row_id'] = df.ix[grouped['argmax']].reset_index(grouped.index).id`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: using a dictionary as the argument for `agg` results in `MultiIndex` columns, so it needs to be `grouped['max_row_id'] = df.ix[grouped['size']['argmax']].reset_index(grouped.index).id`. I'll update my answer to make this clearer

Comment: I was looking at this in more detail and in the solution above, `np.argmax` does not return the index of the corresponding row in `df`. For let's say the `one - black` couple, it returns the row number of the `df.ix[(df['code'] == 'one') & (df['colour'] == 'black')]` with the highest `size` value. So the solution for getting `max_row_id` is not quite right.

Comment: I solved it, in your answer `np.argmax` needs to be replaced by `pd.Series.idxmax`. I edited and re-accepted your answer.