# Pandas GroupBy on subsets of same DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements, dataframe

This question is an extension to [my earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203136/pandas-dataframe-groupby-displaying-group-statistics). I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
codes = ["one","two","three"];
colours = ["black", "white"];
textures = ["soft", "hard"];
N= 100 # length of the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : range(1,N+1),
                    'weeks_elapsed' : [random.choice(range(1,25)) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'code' : [random.choice(codes) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'colour': [random.choice(colours) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'texture': [random.choice(textures) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'size': [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'scaled_size': [random.randint(100,1000) for i in range(1,N+1)]
                   },  columns= ['id', 'weeks_elapsed', 'code','colour', 'texture', 'size', 'scaled_size'])
```

I group it by `colour` and `code` and get some statistics on `size` and `scaled_size` as below:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['code', 'colour']).agg( {'size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax],'scaled_size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax]}).reset_index()
```

Now, what I want to do it is to run the above calculations on the `df` multiple times for different `weeks_elapsed` intervals. **Below is a brute-force solution, is there a more succint and faster way to run this?**  Also, how can I concatenate the results for different intervals in a single dataframe?

```
cut_offs= [4,12]
grouped = {c:{} for c in cut_offs}
for c in cut_offs:
   grouped[c] =df.ix[df.weeks_elapsed <= c ].groupby(['code', 'colour']).agg( 
                                                 {'size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size,pd.Series.idxmax],
                                                  'scaled_size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax]
                                                 }).reset_index()
```

I am particularly interested in the `np.avg` and `np.size` for the different `weeks_elapsed` intervals.

Comment: Can you correct your code for the initial df? 'weeks_elapsed' versus 'w_elapsed' in colums, the same for 'adjust_size' versus 'scaled_size'

Comment: sorry, corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

So this is not a fully working answer, but maybe it can be extended to ultimatively get you there.

```
filter = array([12, 4])
for f in filter:
        df.loc[(df['weeks_elapsed'] <= f), 'filter'] = f
```

Now, `df` looks like

```
>>> df.head()
Out[384]: 
   id  weeks_elapsed   code colour texture  size  adjusted_size  filter
0   1             20    one  white    soft    64            494     NaN
1   2              3  three  white    hard    22            650       4
2   3             22    two  black    hard    41            770     NaN
3   4              2    two  black    hard     4            325       4
4   5              4    two  black    hard    19            536       4
```

Where `filter` contains the **smallest** group that the row belong to. The next step would be

```
>>> df.groupby(['filter', 'code', 'colour']).agg({'size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax],
                                    'adjusted_size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax]}
).reset_index()
Out[387]: 
    filter   code colour  adjusted_size                            size  \
                                    sum     average  size  idxmax   sum   
0        4    one  black           2195  548.750000     4      45   142   
1        4    one  white            286  286.000000     1      81    58   
2        4  three  black            927  463.500000     2      99   121   
3        4  three  white           5850  585.000000    10      95   511   
4        4    two  black           1102  367.333333     3       4    94   
5        4    two  white            852  852.000000     1      75     2   
6       12    one  white           2499  499.800000     5      72   267   
7       12  three  black           4709  588.625000     8      84   431   
8       12  three  white            569  189.666667     3      97   171   
9       12    two  black           2446  611.500000     4      49   241   
10      12    two  white           2859  714.750000     4      43   203   


      average  size  idxmax  
0   35.500000     4       5  
1   58.000000     1      81  
2   60.500000     2      99  
3   51.100000    10      88  
4   31.333333     3      21  
5    2.000000     1      75  
6   53.400000     5      69  
7   53.875000     8      12  
8   57.000000     3      59  
9   60.250000     4      36  
10  50.750000     4      43
```

**However, these are not exactly the groups you were looking for: observations with `filter=4` will only be in the group belonging to `4`, not in the group with `filter=12`.**

I tried looking at expanding_mean, however that will only be row-wise. So far, this is incomplete, but maybe it helps someone else to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is an alternative. The only way to have **overlapping groups**, which is effectively what you want, by my research (I'm only learning myself) is apparently `TimeGrouper`. That one, however, needs your data to be in a time-range. One way to achieve this is the following:

```
filter = array([25, 12, 4]) # we need 25 here so we don't have NaN values later on
for i,f in enumerate(filter):
    df.loc[(df['weeks_elapsed'] <= f), 'filter'] = i + 1
df2 = df.set_index([pd.DatetimeIndex('2014-01-'+df['filter'].astype(int).astype(str))])
results = df2.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['code', 'colour']).agg(
    {'size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax],
     'scaled_size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax]
    }).reset_index())
```

Now `results` contains everything in the weird format. Transform it back

```
results.set_index(results.index.get_level_values(0).day, drop=True, inplace=True)
results.set_index(filter[results.index.values - 1], drop=True)
Out[490]: 
     code colour  scaled_size                   scaled_size  size             \
                          sum     average  size      idxmax   sum    average   
25    one  black         4655  517.222222     9  2014-01-01   331  36.777778   
25    one  white         2444  305.500000     8  2014-01-01   292  36.500000   
25  three  black         2068  344.666667     6  2014-01-01   246  41.000000   
25  three  white         2859  571.800000     5  2014-01-01   260  52.000000   
25    two  black         6330  575.454545    11  2014-01-01   599  54.454545   
25    two  white         3200  533.333333     6  2014-01-01   291  48.500000   
12    one  black         4004  667.333333     6  2014-01-02   331  55.166667   
12    one  white         2965  741.250000     4  2014-01-02   130  32.500000   
12  three  black         3040  608.000000     5  2014-01-02   344  68.800000   
12  three  white         3795  474.375000     8  2014-01-02   359  44.875000   
12    two  black         2198  314.000000     7  2014-01-02   323  46.142857   
12    two  white         3427  571.166667     6  2014-01-02   271  45.166667   
4     one  black         1501  500.333333     3  2014-01-03    73  24.333333   
4     one  white         1710  570.000000     3  2014-01-03   210  70.000000   
4   three  black         1461  730.500000     2  2014-01-03    14   7.000000   
4   three  white          961  480.500000     2  2014-01-03    14   7.000000   
4     two  black         1656  552.000000     3  2014-01-03   189  63.000000   
4     two  white         2462  410.333333     6  2014-01-03   352  58.666667   

               size  
    size     idxmax  
25     9 2014-01-01  
25     8 2014-01-01  
25     6 2014-01-01  
25     5 2014-01-01  
25    11 2014-01-01  
25     6 2014-01-01  
12     6 2014-01-02  
12     4 2014-01-02  
12     5 2014-01-02  
12     8 2014-01-02  
12     7 2014-01-02  
12     6 2014-01-02  
4      3 2014-01-03  
4      3 2014-01-03  
4      2 2014-01-03  
4      2 2014-01-03  
4      3 2014-01-03  
4      6 2014-01-03
```

Answer (score 1):

@FooBar's answer may be better (haven't fully digested it), but here's one other approach.

First create a function that returns a custom average function, based on your filter condition.  The inner function will take just the series, the outer function defines what value to filter on, and what dataframe that series is from.

```
In [248]: def filter_average(base_df, filter_value, filter_by='weeks_elapsed'):
     ...:     def inner(x):
     ...:         return np.average(x[base_df[filter_by] <= filter_value])
     ...:     inner.__name__ = 'avg<=' + str(filter_value)
     ...:     return inner
```

Then, in your groupby operation, build versions of the filter average function for different cutoffs with a list comprehension, as below.  The `__name__` line above is necessary so that the headings under size are distinct.

```
In [249]: df.groupby(['code','colour']).agg({'size': [filter_average(df, i) 
                                                      for i in cut_offs]})
Out[249]: 
                   size           
                  avg<=4    avg<=12
code  colour                      
one   black   55.166667  56.555556
      white   81.750000  58.583333
three black         NaN  32.000000
      white   40.333333  36.400000
two   black   32.000000  37.714286
      white   95.000000  45.000000
```

The same approach could be used `np.size` and could maybe be even built into a more generic decorator.